# How do I find the mode digit with the least number of instruction counts?

Tags: assembly, mips

The input from the user is meant to determine whether the number (max. 20 digits) is a palindrome, but I also need to find the mode digit subsequently.
If the mode digit is tied, the digit with the greatest value should be printed.

I can use basic branches, loads and operators such as divide, multiply and add.

Currently my number palindrome method just compares character by character after finding the length of the input string.

UPDATE:
Created a solution using the idea of the counter array. I counted the number of occurrences of each digit during the count loop that finds the string's length.
In the find_mode loop, I later iterate through the counters array and compare each number of occurrences.
Probably not the optimal (least instruction counts) but it works.
Thank you gusbro for the guidance!

```
    .data
buf1:   .space  21     # receive original input in this buffer
counters: .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 # counters for digits 0-9 for number of occurrences

# the following are constant strings that you can use for your prompts and messages
msgin:  .asciiz "Enter up to 20 digits without spaces: "
msg1:   .asciiz "\nYour string: "
msg2:   .asciiz " IS a palindrome\n"
msg3:   .asciiz " IS NOT a palindrome\n"
msg4:   .asciiz "\nThe mode digit is: "

# print this string for a newline character
nline:  .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main:
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, msgin
syscall # print msgin
li $v0, 8
la $a0, buf1
la $a1, 20
syscall # read string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg1
syscall # print msg1
li $v0, 4
la $a0, buf1
syscall # print user input

la $a1,buf1
add $t3, $0, $0 # counter of input length

count:
lb $t1,($a1)
beq $t1, 10, initialize # branches if it reaches the LF character

#this part is for the mode digit counters
subu $t1, $t1, '0'
lb $t2, counters($t1)
addi $t2, $t2, 1
sb $t2, counters($t1) # update counters(i)

addi $t3, $t3, 1 # increase counter
addi $a1,$a1,1 # traverse the string
b count

initialize:
la $a1, buf1 # sets up pointer going forwards
la $a2, buf1 # sets up pointer going backwards

div $t4, $t3, 2 # get the amount needed to traverse backwards, so that odd number palindromes work too

addi $t3, $t3, -1 # last digit will be at (input length - 1)
add $a2, $a2, $t3 # move the second pointer to the last digit

check:
beq $t4, $0, isPalindrome # if the traverse counter = 0, nothing left to traverse
lb $t1, ($a1) # starting digit
lb $t2, ($a2) # ending digit
bne $t1, $t2, isNotPalindrome
addi $t4, $t4, -1 # reduce amount to traverse by 1
addi $a1,$a1,1 # move pointer forwards
addi $a2,$a2,-1 # move pointer backwards   
b check

isPalindrome:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg2
syscall # print is palindrome
b mode

isNotPalindrome:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg3
syscall # print not palindrome
b mode

mode:   
addi $t7, $0, 0 # counter for number of occurrences
add $t6, $0, $0 # counter to know if done iterating
addi $t5, $0, 0 # the mode digit
la $a1, counters

find_mode:
beq $t6, 10, print # stops iterating through
lb $t1, ($a1)
bge $t1, $t7, store_mode # number of occurences are higher, go store the new mode digit
addi $t6, $t6, 1 # moves counter forward
addi $a1, $a1, 1 # moves pointer forward
b find_mode

store_mode:
add $t7, $t1, $0 # stores the highest number of occurrences
add $t5, $t6, $0 #stores the actual number
addi $t6, $t6, 1 #moves counter forward
addi $a1, $a1, 1 # moves pointer forward
b find_mode

print:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg4
syscall
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5 # prints mode digit
syscall

exit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: The palindrome part is easy: if the number is equal to its reverse, it's a palindrome. Reversing a string is easy. What I don't understand is what is the "mode digit", and how it is "tied".

Comment: Just to clarify, my palindrome method is functioning correctly. Mode digit is the number of times a digit occurs in the string, and if a couple of digits both have the biggest number of occurrences, they are tied as the mode digit, but the one with the greater value should be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an array of 10 counters (one for each digit).
When you compute whether the string is a palindrome you can update those counters:
First declare the array in the data section:

```
counters: .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   # counters for 10 digits
```

Then update the counters when you check if the string is palindrome

```
addi $a2,$a2,-1 #move pointer backwards  --- your code
  subu $t1, $t1, '0'
  lb $t2, counters($t1)
  addi $t2, $t2, 2
  sb $t2, counters($t1) # update counters(i)
b check  # --------your code
```

If it is palindrome you still have to take into account whether the string was even or odd (to count the middle digit if it was not taken into account):

```
# This code should go after you print that the string is palindrome
# Update counter if string was odd
  andi $t3, $t3, 1
  bnez $t3, even
  lb $t1, ($a1)
  subu $t1, $t1, '0'
  lb $t2, counters($t1)
  addi $t2, $t2, 1
  sb $t2, counters($t1) # update counters(i)
even:
```

Now do a linear search over the counters to get the mode:

```
  addu $a1, $0, 9
  xor $t2, $t2, $t2
find_mode:
  lb $t1, counters($a1)
  ble $t1, $t2, not_mode
  move $t2, $t1
  move $t3, $a1
not_mode:  
  subu $a1, $a1, 1
  bnez $a1, find_mode
```

and print the results...

```
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, msg4
  syscall
  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $t3
  syscall
```

Comment: I have been trying to follow along, but I decided to put the counter inside the initial count loop so that I don't have to consider the even/odd middle digit thing. 
    count:
    lb $t1,($a1)
    beq $t1, 10, initialize
    subu $t1,$t1,'0'  
    lb $t2, counters($t1)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    sb $t2, counters($t1)
    addi $t3, $t3, 1 # increase counter
    addi $a1,$a1,1 # traverse the string
    b count

but now when i go back to find_mode, i can't seem to access the counters. doing la $a1, counters followed by lb $t1, ($a1) just gives me a runtime exception.. why is this?

Comment: @glew: check the edit. The code that updates the counter if the string was odd can be done after printing that the string is palindrome, and the linear search and printing of the results (mode) can go after that...

Comment: @glew: maybe you are modifying `$a1` wrongly after the `la $a1, counters`

Comment: Oh maybe I should have clarified, even if the string is not a palindrome, I should be calculating the mode digit, which is why I was trying to modify it to fit that situation. Otherwise, the code works for finding mode digit, but only when the string is a palindrome.